# Block repeated remote logon attempts with Windows Server 2003

Tags: networking, security, windows-server-2003, login-retrictions

I have a machine running Windows Server 2003 that is connected to the Internet, and I've noticed several events in the event log that state the following:

> The server was unable to logon the
>   Windows NT account 'Administrator' due
>   to the following error: Logon failure:
>   unknown user name or bad password.

The source for this event is MSFTPSVC, and the same event occured about 3 times every second from midnight to 6:30am. It's kind of ridiculous that our server allowed so many attempts. Is there a way to keep someone from attempting to log on after the first few unsuccessful tries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you set this via group policy / computer security policy - however, by default, the Administrator account does not allow lock outs but what I advise you do is rename the administrator account - or disable it.

Comment: I found it in Administrative Tools / Local Security Policy / Account Policies / Accout Lockout Policy. Is this what you are talking about, or is there another place I need to change it?

Comment: It depends - local security policy is fine if this machine is stand alone and it is the local administrator that they are attempting to login as. Otherwise, if it is a domain, you will want to do the domain security policy to change the domain administrator password... As you said Win 2K3, I incorrectly just assumed it was a domain pc.